# Using for-loop to compare multiple investment options

Tags: java, finance

The multiplier in the for-loop is changed with each passing year, however for some reason it is not being applied when the yearly calculation is being computed.  Right now the only multiplier that is working is when the user inputs values 1-12 when prompted how many times the interest is compounded per year.  Typically interest is compounded either daily, monthly, quarterly, or yearly.  It is not working for daily.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    /**
       This program compares CD /Investment plans input by the year
       broken down by the requirements below:

       This program creates a table of compound interest investment growth over time
       Broken down by: a) year b) balance at end of year
       Finance formula of A= P(1+ r/n)^n*t is used:
       A = Future Value         | P = Initial Investment
       r = annual interest rate |n = times interest is compounded/year
       t = years invested
    */ 

     public class InvestmentTableFirstTest
     {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
             Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

             String bestBankName = "";
             double bestGrowth = 0;
             boolean done = false;

             while(!done)
             {
                 System.out.print("Plan name (one word, Q to quit): ");
                 String bankName = in.next();
                 if (bankName.equals("Q"))
                 {
                       done = true;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                      System.out.print("Please enter your principal investment: ");
                      final double PRINCIPAL_INVESTMENT = in.nextDouble();
                      System.out.print("Please enter the annual interest rate: ");
                      double iRate = in.nextDouble();
                      System.out.print("Please enter number of times interest is compounded per year:  ");
                      final double INCREMENT = in.nextDouble();      
                      System.out.print("Enter number of years: ");
                      int nyears = in.nextInt();

                      iRate = iRate/100; System.out.println("iRate:" + iRate);

                      //Print the table of balances for each year

                       for (int year = 1; year <= nyears; year++)
                       {
                        double MULTIPLIER = INCREMENT * year;
                        System.out.println("Multiplier: " + MULTIPLIER); // I've included this print statement to show that the multiplier changes with each passing year
                        double interest = 1 + (iRate/INCREMENT);
                        double balance = PRINCIPAL_INVESTMENT;
                        double growth =  balance * Math.pow(interest, MULTIPLIER);
                        growth = growth - PRINCIPAL_INVESTMENT;                      
                        balance = balance + growth;                                  
                        System.out.printf("Year: %2d  Interest Earned:   $%.2f\t   Ending Balance:   $%.2f\n", year, growth, balance);

                       if (bestBankName.equals("") || bestGrowth > growth) // || bestBankName > growth
                       {
                            bestBankName = bankName;  // bestBankName = bankName
                            bestGrowth = growth; // mostGrow = growth
                       }
                          System.out.println("Earning with this option: " + growth);        
                  }
             }

         } 
            System.out.println("Best Growth: " + bestBankName);
            System.out.println("Amount Earned: " + bestGrowth);       
       }
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `if (bestBankName.equals("") || bestGrowth` **`<`** `growth)`

Comment: Learn to use debugger and run your code step-by-step.

Comment: Same result as chancea's comment, but this version is more intuitive for me.  if (growth > bestGrowth) { bestGrowth=growth; bestBankName=bankName; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple error. You're comparing `(bestBankName.equals("") || bestGrowth > growth)` , which is if your current growth (so the first bank set) has a growth higher than the second bank. In other words, you flipped the arrow. You need to do `if (bestBankName.equals("") || bestGrowth < growth)` instead.

Comment: That worked out perfectly for me.  Fixed the error and is now printing out the bank with the best growth option.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer so much as a learning opportunity (I hope it doesn't violate any SO laws). As you ease into design fundamentals, this variant might be helpful to look at as an example of using a simple value object.

I left most of the logic as you presented it.

Value class definition & main():

**InvestmentTableFirstTest.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InvestmentTableFirstTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String bestBankName = "";
        double bestGrowth = 0.0;
        List<InvestmentOption> investmentOptions = new ArrayList<InvestmentOption>();

        // some information for testing
        InvestmentOption boa = new InvestmentOption("Bank of America", 5000, 1.15, 12, 5);
        InvestmentOption st = new InvestmentOption("Sun Trust", 5000, 2.3, 12, 5);
        InvestmentOption wf = new InvestmentOption("Wells Fargo", 5000, 5.3, 12, 5);

        investmentOptions.add(boa);
        investmentOptions.add(st);
        investmentOptions.add(wf);

        // you could wrap this with conditional logic to obtain multiple
        // investment profiles from the user.
        InvestmentOption userProvided = getInvestmentOptionFromUser(scanIn);
        investmentOptions.add(userProvided);

        // iterate over each bank in the list, evaluate growth
        // and update 'best bank' if the bank being evaluated
        // provides better growth than the current 'best bank'
        for (InvestmentOption currentInvestmentOption : investmentOptions)
        {
            String bankName = currentInvestmentOption.getBankName();
            double PRINCIPAL_INVESTMENT = currentInvestmentOption.getInvestment();
            double iRate = currentInvestmentOption.getInterestRate() /100;
            double INCREMENT = currentInvestmentOption.getCompoundPerYear();
            double nyears = currentInvestmentOption.getYears();
            double MULTIPLIER, interest, balance, growth = 0.0;

            // calculate growth
            for (int year = 1; year <= nyears; year++)
            {
                MULTIPLIER = INCREMENT * year;
                interest = 1 + (iRate/INCREMENT);
                balance = PRINCIPAL_INVESTMENT;
                growth =  balance * Math.pow(interest, MULTIPLIER);
                growth = growth - PRINCIPAL_INVESTMENT;
            }

            currentInvestmentOption.setGrowth(growth);
            System.out.println("Earning with " + bankName + "  " + growth);

            // compare earnings. If the bank being evaluated in this
            // iteration provides a better investment, set it as the
            // best investment option
            if (currentInvestmentOption.getGrowth() > bestGrowth)
            {
                bestGrowth = currentInvestmentOption.getGrowth();
                bestBankName = currentInvestmentOption.getBankName() ;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nBest Growth: " + bestBankName);
        System.out.println("Amount Earned: " + bestGrowth);
    }

    private static InvestmentOption getInvestmentOptionFromUser(Scanner in)
    {
        InvestmentOption iOption;
        String bankName;
        double principalInvestment, iRate, increment;
        int nyears;

        System.out.print("Plan name : ");
        bankName = in.next();
        System.out.print("Please enter your principal investment: ");
        principalInvestment = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter the annual interest rate: ");
        iRate = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Please enter number of times interest is compounded per year:  ");
        increment = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter number of years: ");
        nyears = in.nextInt();

        iOption = new InvestmentOption(bankName, principalInvestment, iRate, increment, nyears);
        return iOption;
    }
}
```

**Investment.java**

```
public class InvestmentOption
{
    private String bankName;
    private double investment;
    private double interestRate;
    private double compoundPerYear;
    private int years;
    private double growth;

    public InvestmentOption(String pBankName, double pInvestment, double pInterestRate, double pCompoundPerYear, int pYears)
    {
        bankName = pBankName;
        investment = pInvestment;
        interestRate = pInterestRate;
        compoundPerYear = pCompoundPerYear;
        years = pYears;
    }

    public double getGrowth()
    {
        return growth;
    }

    public void setGrowth(double pGrowth)
    {
        growth = pGrowth;
    }

    public String getBankName()
    {
        return bankName;
    }


    public double getInvestment()
    {
        return investment;
    }

    public double getInterestRate()
    {
        return interestRate;
    }

    public double getCompoundPerYear()
    {
        return compoundPerYear;
    }

    public int getYears()
    {
        return years;
    }
}
```

Comment: Totally understand where you're coming from.  Maybe I wasn't as clear as I should have been.  I am trying to design this program to be completely user dependent with no pre-set variables (i.e., principal investments, interest rates, years invested).  This allows the user to search for interest rates on their own and compare any bank or plan that they see against another.